# CPanel Pulling Specific data from github repo

Tags: codeigniter, github, version-control, cpanel, pull-request

I have two cPanel Accounts and 1 Github repo

from 1st cPanel account i want to push all the data to Github

but on 2nd cPanel account i only want to pull specific files and folders,
like, applications/controllers , applications/modules, applications/views etc
without removing or updating the other files already in my 2nd cPanel account

how can i do this? its a codeigniter project.

i tried to by making branch where i pushed the data fro 2nd account but that's not helping as it removes my current files in 2nd cPanel account.